# RedisClient state is disconnected

Tags: java, redis, vert.x

I'm using RedisClient with Vert.x on Windows. When I debug, the RedisClient state is disconnected and my API is not working.

Here's my code:

public class RedisClientVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

```
public static final int PORT = 8080;
private RedisClient redis;


@Override
public void start(Future future) throws Exception {
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    ServiceDiscovery.create(vertx, serviceDiscovery -> {
        RedisDataSource.getRedisClient(serviceDiscovery, rec -> rec.getName().equals("redis"), ar -> {
            if (ar.failed()) {
                redis = RedisClient.create(vertx, new RedisOptions().setHost("127.0.0.1").setPort(6381));
            } else {
                redis = ar.result();
            }

            router.route("/api/dogs*").handler(BodyHandler.create());
            router.post("/api/dogs").handler(this::addItem);

            vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(PORT, res -> {
                if (res.succeeded()) {
                    System.out.println("Server listening on port: " + PORT);

                  future.complete();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to start server.");
                    future.fail(res.cause());
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

private void addItem(RoutingContext context) {
    String body = context.getBodyAsString();
    if (body != null) {
        final Dog dog = Json.decodeValue(body, Dog.class);
        redis.hset("my-dogs-list", dog.getBreed(), Integer.toString(dog.getAge()), res -> {
            if (res.failed()) {
                context.fail(res.cause());
            } else {
                getAll(context);
            }
        });
    } else {
        context.response().setStatusCode(400).end();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Update: I get the same error when I use the default port.

Comment: The error is: io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase
SEVERE: Unexpected exception in route
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:6379